# Python - proper way of importing own modules

Tags: python, module, virtualenv, python-import

I got a bit confused about importing own modules in Python. I think I have a big lack of understanding here. Let's suppose I've created a few months ago my own module in Python2 using virtualenv and this module uses some old versions of external modules from PyPI stored in requirments.txt. Now I want to use methods from classes from that old module in my new Python3 program. How should I import the old module properly? As I understand this will be requiring interpreting my code by Python3 and that old module by Python2. I can't understand how that is achievable. In fact I managed to get it working but I think I did it by going really around how it should be done in fact. I did some research on the Internet but this didn't help me solve my understading problem.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Separating into modules, classes, functions etc. will only help you keep your code structured. When running the script, all the code will be compiled together. You cannot ask python to interpret module A as python 2.7 code and another module B as python 3.6 code.

Comment: Hmm... So I need to create virtualenv for my new project, set it up with requirements.txt of that older project right? That will give me correct versions of external packages used by old module. Am I right? 

Aspect with two interpreters at one time is clear.

But where should I store my old module to import it properly? In the same folder as my new project? Can I move it to LIB of interpreter? I know that it will work if I put in my project folder but how is it done normally?

Comment: Yes, you'll need a new virtualenv for Python 3 and install the packages from requirements.txt. And then, if the syntax of your own module is already compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3, you can be lazy and just add the path containing your module to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. They gave me some basics to understand the problem. :)